# Carousel places indicator and captions below image in responsive mode

Tags: html, css, carousel

This is the code for my carousel. It works great when in full screen, but responsive places the captions and carousel indicators below the image. How do I fix this? I've tried a lot of various things.

```
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="/img/courtyard.png" alt="First slide"> <!--IMAGE SIZE 1080px x 550px-->
                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                    <p align="left">
                        <a id="hero-caption" href="#">
                            <span style="font-size: 200%;"> 
                                ...
                            </span>
                            <br>
                            <span style="font-size: 350%;"> 
                                ...
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="/img/openfield.png" alt="Second slide"> <!--IMAGE SIZE 1080px x 550px-->
                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                    <h5>...</h5>
                    <p>...</p>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap v4.5

Your question is not accurate enough, but
You added class `d-none` which set property `display: none !important;` so carousel captions is not display below 768px and in responsive places the captions and carousel indicators can`t be below the image.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/display/#hiding-elements

You need to remove styles for fonts also.

Look at this example (more you can find in https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/carousel/):

```
<div id="carouselExampleCaptions" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                <div class="carousel-caption d-block">
                    <h5>First slide label</h5>
                    <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                <div class="carousel-caption d-block">
                    <h5>Second slide label</h5>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                <div class="carousel-caption d-block">
                    <h5>Third slide label</h5>
                    <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```